# Is there a std::unique-style library algorithm that has user-defined collision handler?

Tags: c++, algorithm, unique, reduce

I have a basic std::vector of key/value pairs. It is sorted by key. I would like to reduce all of the adjacent duplicate key entries using a user-defined binary operator while compacting the vector.

This is basically a std::unique application where the user can decide how to handle the collision rather than just keeping the first entry.

Is there a library algorithm that satisfies this requirement? I can write my own but I would prefer to rely on something that an expert has written.

The map-as-sorted-vector is core to other parts of the algorithm and can't be changed. I am limited to C++14.

Comment: I'm reasonably certain the standard doesn't contain an algorithm specifically for the task you've outlined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a standard algo for this.  `std::unique` almost satisfies the requirement, but unfortunately the BinaryPredicate you supply to compare elements isn't allowed to modify them (*"binary_pred shall not apply any non-constant function through the dereferenced iterators."* - [algorithms.requirements] paragraph 7 in the C++17 Standard) - a requirement that lets the implementation optimise more freely (e.g. parallel processing of different parts of the vector).

An implementation's not too hard though...

```
template <typename Iterator, typename BinaryPredicate, typename Compaction>
Iterator compact(Iterator begin, Iterator end, BinaryPredicate equals, Compaction compaction)
{
    if (begin == end) return begin;
    Iterator compact_to = begin;
    while (++begin != end)
        if (equals(*begin, *compact_to))
            compaction(*compact_to, *begin);
        else
            *++compact_to = *begin;
    return ++compact_to;
}
```

The return value will be the new "end" for the compacted vector - you can `erase` therefrom like you would for `remove_if`.

You can see it running [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dfdb6fabaf845642).

Comment: Yes, thank you @Tony, this workaround is basically what I've been using.